# Issue selecting specific levels of windows application logs in NXLog

Tags: windows, event-viewer, nxlog

I'm trying to pass only Warning / Error / Critical level Application Logs through NXLog to my ELK stack.  When I have this configuration

`<Input EventLog_In>
    Module      im_msvistalog
    # this kinda works for me, put * to get everything
    Query       <QueryList>\
                    <Query Id="0">\
                        <Select Path="Application">*</Select>\
            </Query>\
                </QueryList>
    Exec to_json();
</Input>`

everything works fine, and I'm collecting all levels of Application logs.  I tried putting in a parameter on the `<Select Path>` line like this

`<Select Path="Application">*[Application/Level=1]</Select>\`

And it craps itself and I get nothing.  NXLog isn't reporting any issue, and I'm not seeing anything on the logstash side of things.

I got the information about Event Viewer querying from this thread and adapted it to my use case: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/543494/query-specific-logs-from-event-log-using-nxlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Apparently the reference for error level isn't Application, it's System. My query now looks like this and works flawlessly

`<Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select>\`

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2, fwiw.